# copy a file from HDFS to local system without using sudo

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to copy the contents of part-r-00000 file , I tried the below code but it shows permission denied. I know this can be done from terminal using sudo . Is there any way to do this using a java program. Help needed

```
config.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://127.0.0.1:54310/");
FileSystem hdFS = FileSystem.get(config);
Path local = new Path("/home/abc/cloud");
Path hdfs = new Path("/home/hduser/all_output/Phase4_OutPut");
if (hdFS.exists(hdfs))
    hdFS.copyToLocalFile(false,new Path(finalP+"/part-r-00000"), local);
else
    System.out.println("NOT COPIED");
```

Comment: do you have permissions to read the file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you have required permissions to access the file
2. You can use hadoop native command to copyToLocal

   Hadoop fs -copyToLocal /hdfslocation /local
   or

   Hadoop fs -get /souce /hdfslocation /local